# PHP Memory error

Tags: php, memory-management

I'm using a php script to create image thumbnails and this error is thrown while creating some thumbs:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 31457280 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 227 bytes)

this is what `top` shows:

```
top - 07:43:49 up 44 days, 22:21,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks: 171 total,   1 running, 170 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   6097648k total,  3459060k used,  2638588k free,   566924k buffers
Swap:  4194296k total,        0k used,  4194296k free,  1991920k cached
```

I haven't looked at optimizing phpthumb code. But is there any other way to free the already used memory? May be a cron job can be used to free this memory on regular intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is probably larger than ~10-15MB. PHP has a limit on the amount of memory it can take up per script (`memory_limit` in `php.ini`)

What happens is that you load an image in memory (And then resize it, creating a second image)...

Change the memory limit if you're allowed, or don't load such large image ...
AFAIK there is no stream image reader ...

If you can't change the memory limit, a workaround might be calling the commandline ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick tools if they're installed ...

Comment: The image loaded is never >200kb. I increased the memory limit from 20mb to 30mb, which was OK for a while and then the error started showing up again! But I'd still like to know how to free the memory.

Comment: The memory limit is not for the system, but for a single PHP instance ... Are you resizing multiple images? Maybe your script is allocating memory for each one and never freeing it? It's difficult to say without seeing your script.

Comment: That doesn't show me any code, just the output. Which is useless :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical php.ini problem, if you are running this script on a VPS or a dedicated server, edit the php.ini file and set memory_limit to 99(or more)MB, also look out for max_run_time as that can stop a script after x number of seconds.

Don't forget to reboot Apache after you have done the changes,

If you are running this on a shared server, you might have some problems trying to solve this as you can't edit the settings file, you can try to set the settings in the actual script, however this usually doesn't .

Comment: This is not a real solution, but a workaround "moar memory nom nom nom" :-) Instead, the best solution would be to fix the script since it's using way more memory then it should.